# How to create an RxSwift Observable that emits the height of the keyboard?

Tags: ios, rx-swift

I'd like to observe the height of the iOS keyboard. How do I do that with RxSwift?

Answer (score 7):

If you are only interested in the height of the keyboard, you can observe `UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame` notifications

```
let keyboardHeight = NotificationCenter.default.rx
  .notification(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardDidChangeFrame)
  .map { notification -> CGFloat in
    (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.height ?? 0
  }
```

Note that here, the height of the keyboard will remain "full" even when it goes off-screen. Those notifications will be interesting only for frame changes due to keyboard's language changes or showing / hiding the auto-complete buttons.

If you'd like to consider the keyboard's frame to be 0 when it goes of-screen, you can combine the above observable with `UIKeyboardWillShow` and `UIKeyboardHide` notifications.

```
let keyboardOnScreenHeight = Observable.from([
  NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow)
    .flatMap { _ in keyboardHeight }
  NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide)
    .map { _ in 0 }
])
.merge()
```

From this, you'll get the values emitted by previously defined `keyboardHeight` when it is onscreen, and 0 when it exits it.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can build an `Observable` that emits the height of the keyboard: https://gist.github.com/laurilehmijoki/193332408964ad53e1cc236387ec6e46